# Reshaping Arrays in Numpy with variables

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to take an array on numpy, add a line of code, append it to the array, and then reshape the entire array back to the translated r. While I'm attempting to use plt.imshow to display it again, it keeps saying that the "total size of new array must be unchanged". Is there a better way to get around this?

```
z = np.array([[[23] * ncols]*nrows]).reshape(nrows, ncols)

for j in range(0,1):
  for i in range(0,ncols):
    np.append(z, [23])

np.reshape(z, nrows+1,ncols)

plt.imshow(z, interpolation='none', cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
```

In addition, what if I iterate j from nrows to ncols? Are there specific edits that would need to happen other than just multiplying both by nrows and ncols?

EDIT: I tried reshaping with

```
np.reshape(z, nrows+2, ncols)
```

which works; however, when doing it with a range from 0 to 100 to check differences, the program takes forever and doesn't actually display new values. Are there better ways to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a numpy array and you want to add two rows.

Let's start by creating our array, called `a`:

```
In [61]: a = np.arange(12); a.resize(3, 4); print a
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Now, let's create the new rows that we want to add to `a`:

```
In [62]: newrow1 = np.array([100, 101, 102, 103])

In [63]: newrow2 = np.array([200, 201, 202, 203])
```

Now, let's add those rows:

```
In [64]: np.vstack((a, newrow1, newrow2))
Out[64]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [100, 101, 102, 103],
       [200, 201, 202, 203]])
```

#### Notes

Let's consider this line of code:

```
z = np.array([[[23] * ncols]*nrows]).reshape(nrows, ncols)
```

Let's try two variations:

```
In [74]: nrows=3; ncols=4; np.array([[[23] * ncols]*nrows])
Out[74]: 
array([[[23, 23, 23, 23],
        [23, 23, 23, 23],
        [23, 23, 23, 23]]])

In [75]: nrows=3; ncols=4; np.array([[[23] * ncols]*nrows]).reshape(nrows, ncols)
Out[75]: 
array([[23, 23, 23, 23],
       [23, 23, 23, 23],
       [23, 23, 23, 23]])
```

We can conclude that the call to reshape is unnecessary because the array, as created, already has the specified number of rows and columns.

Now, let's consider this loop:

```
for j in range(0,1):
   for i in range(0,ncols):
      np.append(z, [23])
```

`np.append` does not change the array in place; it returns a new array.  Consequently, this loop does nothing.

Let's consider `reshape`:

```
np.reshape(z, nrows+1,ncols)
```

As you noted, with `reshape`, the "total size of new array must be unchanged".  The solution is to use `resize`.  Here, we demonstrate `resize` on array `a`:

```
In [86]: a
Out[86]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [91]: a = np.resize(a, (5,4)); print a
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]]
```

If you want all of the last two rows to have the value `23`, then it can be simply assigned:

```
In [94]: a[3:, :] = 23; print a
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [23 23 23 23]
 [23 23 23 23]]
```